# How to generate path relative to module path

Tags: go, module, path

Say my module path in go.mod is: `module github.com/User/Project`, and I have a file structure like so:

```
.
├── go.mod
└── pkg
    └── folder
        └── ...
```

Is there a way to run a Go program that will print, depending on the folder you are in, the path relative to the module path?

Example:

```
$ (~) ./executable
$ (~) github.com/User/Project
```

```
$ (~/pkg/) ./executable
$ (~/pkg/) github.com/User/Project/pkg
```

```
$ (~/pkg/folder) ./executable
$ (~/pkg/folder) github.com/User/Project/pkg/folder
```

My thought process so far is to use os.Getwd() and exec.cmd("go", "env", "GOMOD").Run() and then parse the go.mod file to find the module path etc..

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to run a Go program that will print, depending on the folder you are in, the path relative to the module path?

No.

Redesign. The proper way to go is making the path to assets a runtime option e.g. via environment variables or command line flags.